# protected members in a sealed class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a WebPart, which means that I inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` and I override the method `protected override void CreateChildControls()`.

However, I'd like to make the class `sealed` if possible, but that gives two issues: Just sealing the class gives a warning "new protected member declared in sealed class".

Changing the access modifier from `protected` to `private` or `internal` gives a compiler error telling me I can't change the modifier when inheriting.

That leaves me wondering: Is there any problem with sealing it and ignoring the warning? Or could this lead to any negative side effects further down the road? It *seems* to work just fine, but the devil is usually in the details.

**Edit:** I was just being stupid. The "new protected member" error was for a function that was indeed NOT overridden and just accidentially was declared as `protected`. Thanks for the Pragma-Tip though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it says there's a *new* protected member declared in the class is slightly worrying.

Hmm... I can't reproduce this in simple test code:

```
using System;

public class Base
{
    protected virtual void Foo()
    {
    }
}

public sealed class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

compiles without warnings with .NET 3.5SP1. Are you *definitely* overriding the base method? Check that you really have got the `override` modifier. (Sorry if that sounds patronising - I'm not trying to accuse you of being lax or anything. I'm just stumped otherwise...)

Answer (score 6):

A protected member can be seen by sub classes so you're slightly altering the interface of the class; If you declare it 'private' it's only ever seen locally so it doesn't affect the interface.

Declare your method private not protected and the warning should go away.

Comment: I ran into this when refactoring from a regular class to a singleton.  This is the answer I was looking for.  Sort of a no-brainer when you really think about it.  Why would a method be "protected" if it is in a class that is "sealed"?  There would never be a deriving class ... so the warning tells you that you are writing code that contradicts the class permissions.  It will work, but the warnings are well placed.  +1 to widgisoft!

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you're overriding correctly? Personally I cannot repro this behavior. But if it worries you, you can use

```
#pragma warning disable 0628
// Offending code
#pragma warning restore 0628
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it is being daft. I'd ignore the warning, after all it's only stating that what you are doing is illogical like having a public ctor on an abstract type. The worst case scenario is a bit of confusion.

I think i've had this as well but only in Compact Framework code, is it Full Framework in this case?